# Examples of decision processes where action has no effect on the next state, but has on the reward?

Tags: time-series, reinforcement-learning, markov-process

Within my studies, I work on a recurrent reinforcement learning project and I struggle to find real-world problems with a property that is important to my solutions. I look for instances of problems which can be modelled similarly to Markov Decision Processes. In them after every state s_t, there's a next state s_(t+1), **but action a_t doesn't impact s_(t+1)**, only the reward r_(t+1). However, we accept information about a_t as a part of s_(t+1) that may change.

A prime example is trading. Consider a price series like (s_t = (5, 5, 6, 5)). Taking an action a_t (e.g., buying) doesn't alter the next state (s_(t+1) = (5, 6, 5, 4)), but it does influence the reward r_(t+1) (e.g., you incur a loss of 10%). The only information that can be in the state that can be dependent on the previous action is what the previous action was. The other very similar problem I found is portfolio optimization - I can take it into account, because:

- there is a series of actions
- actions take into account previous action (current weights of assets) and the state (e.g. historical prices)
- choice of action doesn't impact the next state (prices don't care about one transaction), but information about previous action is an exception
- the reward is calculated based on a series of historical actions and states (e.g rate of return, I know that there are also immediate rewards, but let's assume we calculate it afterwards)

Could you find more instances of such a problem? Of course, it doesn't have to be associated with finance. It's also important that the output of the model could be interpreted as a decision, rather than not continuous output.

Edit:
I came up with the idea that I can achieve such an environment, when states can be described as a Markov Chain, so it could be not only financial markets but also e.g. weather. Maybe someone will find it helpful to ideate some instances of problem I seek.

I also came up with catching similar problems like outliers detection in time series or real-time trend detection and modelling them as RRL problems.